# ASP NET Core 2.2 Virtual Paths

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.2

I am currently trying to deploy a .NET ASP.NET Core (V2.2) app to IIS. The deployment worked fine but when it comes to virtual directories and routing I have issues. For example I am using

```
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
```

When I am using http://localhost without a virtual directory it works as expected. Every time an exception is thrown the application redirects me to the following controller-action

```
    [Route("Error/500")]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error500(){}
```

Now if I deploy the application to http://localhost/myapp every time an exception is thrown the application redirects me to http://localhost/Error/500 and NOT to http://localhost/myapp/Error/500. And as I result the page is not loaded. I have tried

```
app.UsePathBase()
```

but it didn't work. I need to set the base url to http://localhost or http://localhost/myapp base on the environment I want to deploy.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have tried to set app.UsePathBase("/myapp"); ? Seems to be doing the trick in my code (.NET Core 2.1).

Comment: Yeah I tried it. It ignores it.